# UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector

Tags: ios, swift, crash, backtrace

I'm getting lots of crashes with the following backtrace and I can't find the cause for it.

According to Apple **-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]** occurs when a new object is allocated in the memory previously occupied by the deallocated object.

> **Note:** Messaging a previously deallocated object may raise an
>   NSInvalidArgumentException instead of crashing the program with a
>   memory access violation. This occurs when a new object is allocated in
>   the memory previously occupied by the deallocated object. If your
>   application is crashing due to an uncaught NSInvalidArgumentException
>   (look for -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] in the
>   exception backtrace), consider profiling your application with the
>   Zombies instrument to eliminate the possibility that improper memory
>   management is the cause.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

But what's up with the rest of the backtrace, especially **-[UIUndoGestureInteraction didMoveToView:]** thing?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae45498c __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ae17d0a4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae35843c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:144)
3   UIKitCore                       0x1b24902a8 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 296 (UIResponder.m:659)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae458e08 ___forwarding___ + 1324 (NSForwarding.m:3325)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae45abec _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
6   UIKitCore                       0x1b2353040 -[UIUndoGestureInteraction didMoveToView:] + 108 (UIUndoGestureInteraction.m:725)
7   UIKitCore                       0x1b28eb3c4 _setInteractionView + 84 (UIView.m:16421)
8   UIKitCore                       0x1b28eb2a0 -[UIView(Dragging) addInteraction:] + 268 (UIView.m:16450)
9   UIKitCore                       0x1b26cd2b8 -[UIEditingOverlayViewController _addInteractions] + 260 (UIEditingOverlayViewController.m:79)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e5b2ec -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 832 (UIViewController.m:4695)
11  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e5b6fc __52-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke + 268 (UIViewController.m:4758)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae42773c __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSArrayHelpers.m:9)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae32b86c -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 152 (NSArrayI.m:108)
14  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e5b49c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 1264 (UIViewController.m:4736)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e5d530 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 44 (UIViewController.m:5272)
16  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e5c32c -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 88 (UIViewController.m:5050)
17  UIKitCore                       0x1b246bca4 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 584 (UIApplication.m:3027)
18  UIKitCore                       0x1b245b7c0 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 232 (UIApplication.m:2986)
19  UIKitCore                       0x1b248b594 _afterCACommitHandler + 76 (UIApplication.m:3048)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae3d1c48 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae3ccb34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416 (CFRunLoop.c:1868)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae3cd100 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308 (CFRunLoop.c:2910)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae3cc8bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
24  GraphicsServices                0x1b8238328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
25  UIKitCore                       0x1b24626d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4753)
26  JustConnect                     0x10425ca60 main + 68 (APIInfoUser.swift:7)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x1ae257460 start + 4
```

Comment: Add the exception breakpoint and see at which line you're getting the exception in your code.

Comment: @PGDev I can't seem to reproduce the crash while debugging. These are crash reports from the AppStore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the response from an Apple Developer & Technical Support:

> The key thing to notice here is that frames 0 through 5 of this
>   backtrace are just boilerplate associated with an unrecognised
>   selector.  That is, frame 6 has called a method on an object, the
>   object didn’t recognise that selector so it entered the Objective-C
>   runtime forwarding infrastructure (frames 5 through 4).  That landed
>   in UIResponder (frame 3) because UIResponder support some sort of
>   generic message forwarding.  That message forwarding failed, so
>   UIResponder called super (frame 2), which then threw the exception.
>
> So the real question is, what’s going on in frame 6.  To learn more
>   about this, you can disassemble the code (-:
>
> ```
> (lldb) disas -n '-[UIUndoGestureInteraction didMoveToView:]'  
> UIKitCore`-[UIUndoGestureInteraction didMoveToView:]:  
>     0x1bbe92fd4 <+0>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-0x30]!  
>     0x1bbe92fd8 <+4>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]  
>     0x1bbe92fdc <+8>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]  
>     0x1bbe92fe0 <+12>:  add    x29, sp, #0x20    ; =0x20   
>     0x1bbe92fe4 <+16>:  mov    x21, x2  
>     0x1bbe92fe8 <+20>:  mov    x19, x0  
>     0x1bbe92fec <+24>:  add    x20, x0, #0x10    ; =0x10   
>     0x1bbe92ff0 <+28>:  mov    x0, x20  
>     0x1bbe92ff4 <+32>:  mov    x1, x2  
>     0x1bbe92ff8 <+36>:  bl     0x1b7cd71d8       ; objc_storeWeak  
>     0x1bbe92ffc <+40>:  cbz    x21, 0x1bbe930a8  ; <+212>  
>     0x1bbe93000 <+44>:  adrp   x8, 208464  
>     0x1bbe93004 <+48>:  add    x1, x8, #0x7b1    ; =0x7b1   
>     0x1bbe93008 <+52>:  mov    x0, x19  
>     0x1bbe9300c <+56>:  bl     0x1b7cb9180       ; objc_msgSend  
>     0x1bbe93010 <+60>:  mov    x0, x20  
>     0x1bbe93014 <+64>:  bl     0x1b7cd7a80       ; objc_loadWeakRetained  
>     0x1bbe93018 <+68>:  mov    x20, x0  
>     0x1bbe9301c <+72>:  adrp   x8, 208304  
>     0x1bbe93020 <+76>:  add    x1, x8, #0xc04    ; =0xc04   
>     0x1bbe93024 <+80>:  bl     0x1b7cb9180       ; objc_msgSend  
>     0x1bbe93028 <+84>:  mov    x29, x29  
>     0x1bbe9302c <+88>:  bl     0x1b7cd8864       ; objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue  
>     0x1bbe93030 <+92>:  mov    x21, x0  
>     0x1bbe93034 <+96>:  adrp   x8, 208502  
>     0x1bbe93038 <+100>: add    x1, x8, #0xbb7    ; =0xbb7   
>     0x1bbe9303c <+104>: bl     0x1b7cb9180       ; objc_msgSend  
>     0x1bbe93040 <+108>: stp    d0, d1, [x19, #0x100]
> ```
>
> There’s a bunch of things you can learn here.  First, frame 6 in the
>   backtrace has an offset of +108, so that actual call that failed is at
>   +104.  An objc_msgSend, has two standard parameters, the target object and the selector.  On 64-bit Arm these map to x0 and x1, respectively.
>
> Let’s look at the selector first.  This is constructed by the two
>   instructions at +96 and +100.  Those two instructions form a
>   PC-relative address.  The adrp instruction (‘add relative to page’)
>   takes the current PC (0x1bbe93034), clears the bottom 12 bits
>   (0x1bbe93000, remember that the historical page size is 4096 [1]), and
>   then takes the literal, shifts it left by 12 bits (208502 << 12), and
>   then adds it in.  The add instruction is much simpler.  It takes the
>   result from the previous calculation and adds 0xbb7 (note the switch
>   from decimal to hex!).
>
> If you run this calculation in the debugger you’ll see this:
>
> ```
> (lldb) p (char*)( 0x1bbe93000+(208502<<12)+0xbb7)  
> (char *) $1 = 0x00000001eed09bb7 "actualSceneBounds"
> ```
>
> So the selector is actualSceneBounds.  Cool.
>
> Now let’s look at the object.  At the time of the call (+104) this is
>   expected to be in x0.  At +92 we see it copy x0 to x21, but this is
>   just a distraction.  Actually x0 is the function result from
>   objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue at +88.  That function takes and
>   returns an object, so x0 is the value returned by the message send at
>   +80.  Doing the same relative page trick we did earlier, we see that the selector for that call is -window.  But what object is that being
>   called on?
>
> Working that out is… well… kinda complex because of the objc_storeWeak
>   / objc_loadWeakRetained dance.  I believe it boils down to the value
>   passed into this method via x2, that is, the third parameter.  Based
>   on the method name, this is clearly a view (remember that, for
>   Objective-C methods, the first two parameters, x0 and x1, hold the
>   target and the selector, so x2 holds the first actual parameter).
>
> So, in summary:
>
> - It seems that this method has a view parameter.
> - It’s requested window.window.screenBounds.
> - The last property access has failed because the thing that’s meant to    be a window doesn’t implement the -screenBounds getter.
>
> I don’t know enough about UIKit to explain the background to that.  I
>   have a couple of suggestions here:
>
> 1. Run the Standard Memory Debugging Tools, and specifically Zombies, to see if they turn up anything useful.  Make sure to exercise the
>      undo gesture, based on the class name of the method we pulled apart.
> 2. If that doesn’t pan out, bounce over to App Frameworks > Cocoa Touch to see if anyone there has any suggestions.
>
> Share and Enjoy
>
> —
>
> [1] On 64-bit Arm the actual page size is typically 64 KiB, but the
>   adrp instruction uses the historical page size of 4096 because it
>   matches the maximum literal size in the add instruction.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/389467

Comment: I have the same issue since iOS 13. Did you find the reason? In my case, I have problems with UITabbarController selectors

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, and it turned out that the crash was happening only in release builds where code was being optimized (and I'm guessing the class initialization/declaration was being skipped before it was referenced)

It wasn't happening in debug builds where code was not being optimized.

As a solution, I updated the build settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level to none even for release builds.

Useful context:
https://medium.com/thecodr/is-your-ios-app-crashing-only-when-you-upload-it-to-testflight-ef27d3cb3ecd